# I'm receiving error when calling base copy constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

Im receiving `error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'rval'` in this code while trying to call base copy ctor explicitly:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;


class Base
{
public:
    Base(const Base& rhs){ cout << "base copy ctor" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(const Derived& rval) { Base(rval) ; cout << "derived copy ctor" << endl; }
      // error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'rval'
};

int main()
{
    Derived a;
    Derived y = a; // invoke copy ctor
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

However if do it like this:

```
Derived(const Derived& rval) { Base::Base(rval) ; cout << "derived copy ctor" << endl; }
```

then is OK.

Why am I asking this?
according to the answers on [StackOwerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501920/base-copy-constructor-not-called)

I do not have to use operator `::` to access base copy ctor,
so why do I receive this error?

btw: I'm using visual studio 2010.

**I'm having one more question:**

Do I have to call base's move constructor in user defined move constructor of derived class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call the base constructor you need to put the call in the member initalization list

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(const Derived& rval) : Base(rval)
    { 
         cout << "derived copy ctor" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: OHHH! yeah :D how did I forgot that lol, can you please answer to my second question? thanks alot!

Comment: @codekiddy I don't know the *exact* rules of whether or not you have to explicitly call the base ctor but as a personal rule i always explicitly call the base class ctor.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean 'move' constructor is the copy constructor - Yes. You will have to call the Base's constructor. Otherwise the definition if the base object within the derived object will not be complete. You can either call a copy constructor or a normal constructor of the base class.