# c++: expected class-name before '{' token

Tags: c++, netbeans

When I try to run this code:

Instructor.cpp:

```
#include "Instructor.h"
#include "Person.h"

using std::string;

Instructor::Instructor() {
    Person();
    salary = 0;
}

Instructor::Instructor(string n, string d, string g, int s) {
    Person(n, d, g);
    salary = s;
}

void Instructor::print() {
    if (gender == "M")
        std::cout << "Mr. ";
    else
        std::cout << "Ms. ";
    Person::print();
    std::cout << "    Instructor, Salary: " << salary << std::endl;
}
```

Instructor.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Instructor: public Person 
{
public:
    Instructor();
    Instructor(std::string n, std::string d, std::string g, int s);
    virtual void print();
protected:
    int salary;
};
```

Person.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    Person(std::string n, std::string d, std::string g);
    virtual void print();
protected:
    std::string name;
    std::string dob;
    std::string gender;
};
```

I receive these errors:

```
In file included from Instructor.cpp:1:0:
Instructor.h:5:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
Instructor.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Instructor::print()’:
Instructor.cpp:16:6: error: ‘gender’ was not declared in this scope
  if (gender == "M")
      ^
Instructor.cpp:20:16: error: cannot call member function ‘virtual void Person::print()’ without object
  Person::print();
```

All three of these errors are confusing me.  If the Instructor class was derived from Person, and within Person the gender field is protected, then why am I receiving `error: ‘gender’ was not declared in this scope`, as well as `error: cannot call member function ‘virtual void Person::print()’ without object`?

I feel like I'm doing something obviously wrong here, such as including the files incorrectly or something like that.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add an include for Person in Instructor.h?

Comment: I tried that, and I get the error: In file included from Instructor.cpp:2:0:
Person.h:4:7: error: redefinition of ‘class Person’
 class Person
       ^
In file included from Instructor.h:4:0,
                 from Instructor.cpp:1:
Person.h:4:7: error: previous definition of ‘class Person’

Comment: If you already have that, then you likely have a double include if there aren't include guards (you're including ``Person.h`` in ``Instructor.h`` and ``Instructor.cpp``, which is also getting the copy from ``Instructor.h``)

Comment: This works, kind of.  Now I'm getting different errors saying redefinition of Person.

Comment: Seriously, [include gaurds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Answer (score 8):

You have to include `person.h` in `instructor.h`, otherwise the token `Person` is unknown to compiler. And when you do this, make sure you remove `person.h` from `instructor.cpp`. Otherwise you will get *re-declaration* error. But common practice is to use `#ifdef` directives in header files to prevent multiple inclusion. like in `person.h`

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H


/// class definition and other code


#endif //PERSON_H
```

or you can use  `#pragma once` in VC++.

Another error is you are not initializing `Person` portion of `Instructor` correctly. In the constructor :

```
Instructor::Instructor(string n, string d, string g, int s) {
  Person(n, d, g); // this will create a temporary `Person` object instead of initializing base part and 
                   // default constructor of `Person` will be used for this `Instructor` object
  salary = s;
}
```

do it like this

```
Instructor::Instructor(string n, string d, string g, int s): Person(n,d,g), salary(s) 
{   }
```

Comment: I did this, now there is only one `#include person.h` in instructor.h and nowhere else, however I am getting `In file included from main.cpp:15:0:
Person.h:4:7: error: previous definition of ‘class Person’
 class Person
       ^
In file included from Instructor.h:4:0,
                 from main.cpp:17:
Person.h:4:7: error: redefinition of ‘class Person’
 class Person
       ^
In file included from main.cpp:15:0:
Person.h:4:7: error: previous definition of ‘class Person’
 class Person`

Comment: @user2628156 place [include directives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: `__PERSON_H__` is a bad idea. That's [reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Answer (score 2):

Several issues:

1. At the time you defined your `Instructor` class, your `Person` class isn't defined yet. You should `#include "Person.h"` at the start of `Instructor.h`, which leads to the second issue...
2. Your headers are not protected against double includes (which is the error you see in your comment above). To fix this, you need an include guard:

   ```
   #ifndef PERSON_H
   #define PERSON_H

   class Person {
        // ...
   };

   #endif
   ```

   The second time this file is included, `PERSON_H` is already defined, so what's between the `#ifndef` and the `#endif` will be ignored.
3. You are calling the base class constructor incorrectly. The correct syntax is:

   ```
   Instructor::Instructor(string n, string d, string g, int s) : Person(n, d, g){
       salary = s;
   }
   ```

   What you are doing (writing `Person(n, d, g);` in the constructor body) will compile, because if you do not explicitly call the base class constructor, the compiler will try to call the parameterless default constructor for you, and in your case, `Person` happens to have a default constructor that can be called (if `Person` does not have a constructor that takes no parameters, you'll get a compile error). However, the effect of that statement is simply to create a temporary `Person` object that gets destructed at the end of the statement, not call the base class constructor.

   This syntax (called a member initialization list) can also be used to initialize other class members, and in fact is the preferred way of doing so:

   ```
   Instructor::Instructor(string n, string d, string g, int s) : Person(n, d, g), salary(s) { }
   ```

Comment: @T.C. " but it's effect is to create a temporary Person object that gets destructed at the end of that statement." is wrong. It will give error. Base class constructor can be called only in initializer list.

Comment: @RakibulHasan It won't be parsed as a base class constructor call. It would be parsed as a temporary object creation - that's the whole point (in this case, the base class isn't abstract, so it would compile just fine). [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a19ed011ab0654a9).

Comment: @T.C. plz check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888101/im-receiving-error-when-calling-base-copy-constructor) and [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/22200/)

Comment: @RakibulHasan That's a different problem - `A(x);` gets parsed as declaring a variable called `x` with type `A`, equivalent to `A x;`, which then causes the redefinition error; `A(x, y);` gets parsed as creating a temporary `A` object, calling the constructor with parameters `x` and `y`, which is then thrown away.

Comment: @RakibulHasan - calling on your expertise, here. Isn't saying "creating a temporary [parent] object" superfluous and incorrect? First, all memory consumption is temporary (everything is thrown away at some point). Second, I am not sure that statement that T.C. made accurately reflects what happens. The parent constructor is called as a part of creating the derived class and the only object that is created is a child object with attributes derived from the parent and specified by the child; however, in order to properly handle the parent portion of the object, the parent destructor is called?

Comment: @Thomas, C++ is a context sensitive language and everything in this world is relative. So "creating a temporary [parent] object" means it is *temporary* in the derived class `constructor`. Surely even OS code is removed from memory when you shut down your PC. A child object [IS-A](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/proper-inheritance.html) parent object in *public inheritance*. Finally this is a basic example, and no heap memory is used, but usually base destructor should be virtual.

Comment: @Thomas We are talking about completely different things here. You are describing what happens during derived object construction: the derived class constructor calls the base class constructor to construct the base class subobject. I'm talking about what happens in OP's code, where he attempts to call the base class constructor the wrong way - but happens to write legal C++ code so that the compiler won't complain. What the OP's code does is to create a separate `Person` object, completely unrelated to the `Instructor` being constructed, and then immediately throw it away.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the compiler encounters the `#include "FileName.h"` preprocessor directive, the compiler attempts to re-load - and, I believe, redefine - the included class. This will result in a compile-time error. You can read more in detail about **include guards** or the **wrapper #ifndef**, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892043/self-sufficient-header-files-in-c-c/1892057#1892057).

In order to "guard" against this, we use **include guards** - *which must appear before any of your code in your header file*.

For example:

```
#ifndef CLASSIDENTIFIER_H // Capitalized letters are convention (see below)
#define CLASSIDENTIFIER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

public ClassIdentifier
{
   // Class Member Declarations
};
#endif
```

The `#ifndef` stands for "if not defined". The following identifier - in all capitals for no reason other than 'that's how it's done' - is by convention also named according to the class name (this enables the compiler to check a number of things, primarily ensuring that - if everyone follows the convention - that no other class of the same name has been included, referenced, or defined in the program.

Logically, one can deduce that the next two **include guards** stand for "define" and "end if not defined".

If you include your `#endif` immediately after the close of your class declaration, e.g. `};#endif`(see above) this will also result in a compile-time error and one that may not be readily apparent (though, I think the compiler is pretty clear with its resulting error message).

The other code I included is, of course, just for the sake of familiarity and a demonstration of what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

A few things need to be fixed:

1. `Instructor.h` needs to have `#include "Person.h"`.  It is needed there so `Instructor` understands what it inherits from.  No need for this include to exist in `Instructor.cpp` if you move it to `Instructor.h` as `Instructor.cpp` has `Instructor.h` included.
2. I am not sure if you intended for `Person` to be an abstract base class, but I don't see a `Person.cpp` or any implementation of any member functions in `Person.h`.  Even if you want `Person` to be an abstract base class, you need to give a function body to the constructor even if it is empty.

   `Person() {};`
3. You are calling `Person::print` in `Instructor::print` without it having an implementation.
4. When using inheritance, you need to utilize member initialization list which calls the base class constructor to initialize the base class's member variables.  In both Instructor constructors, using the `Person` constructors in the function body as you are currently doesn't lead to the desired result.
   Furthermore, using initialization lists is more efficient and the accepted convection for setting the class's own member variables.

   `Instructor::Instructor() : Person(), salary(0) { }`

   `Instructor::Instructor(string n, string d, string g, int s) : Person(n, d, g), salary(s) { }`

Answer (score -1):

Isnt it just the order of including header files in Instructor.cpp? You will have to include Person.h first and then Instructor.h. Thats It.

Comment: Having the correctness of the program depend on the order in which header files are included is *very* bad form. Headers should always be [self-sufficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892043/self-sufficient-header-files-in-c-c).